# Create CSS Style Sheet Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a CSS Style Sheet using javascript. The code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function colorSquare()
{
 var elem = document.getElementById("body");
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = "<style>";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += ".myAnimation";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "{";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "width: 50px";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "height: 50px";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "position: absolute;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "background: #0000FF;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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)"
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0000FF 0%, #0000FF 0%, #ff0000 100%);";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#0000FF), color-stop(0%,#ff0000), color-stop(100%,#ff0000));";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0000FF 0%,#0000FF 0%,#ff0000 100%);";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0000FF 0%,#0000FF 0%,#ff0000 100%);";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #0000FF 0%,#0000FF 0%,#ff0000 100%);";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #0000FF 0%,#0000FF 0%,#ff0000 100%)";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0000FF', endColorstr='#ff0000',GradientType=1 );";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "border-style: solid;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "border-width: 3px;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "border-color:#77dd77;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "border-radius: 5px;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px black;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "box-shadow:0 0 10px black;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "text-align: white;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "text-align: center;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "line-height: 45px;";
 document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "</style>}";

}
</script>
```

Am I doing this right? If not what is the proper way of using javascript to create a CSS Style Sheet.

Thanks,

Isaiah

Comment: I do not get it, simple question - why not loading a css file?

Comment: Because I need to make many CSS Style Sheets using user input. For example, the background color will be based on user input. I'm just taking one step at a time.

Comment: yeah, I don't like how you're doing it but if it works for you, then what's the question?

Comment: It would work better if you append all your css to a string variable first and then append that to the body. @JoshStevens has provided a good solution.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your code may work (not sure without testing) it looks messy..and you should be putting the css in the head really.

you could do something like this .. you can add as many styles as you want to your `newCSS` variable, meaning the code will look a lot nicer to the eye but also function a lot better with less lines of code.

```
// add your styles here
var newCSS = '.myAnimation { width: 50px; }';
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Thank you Josh for your solution.

Comment: no worries.. this way is a lot neater for you.. just in long run its neater to maintain and for people to understand :) + its less lines of code

Comment: up voted, but with a question. If you append to the head then won't styles already in the body take precedence?  So might it be better to append the user custom styles to the body as OP has done?

Comment: you would normally have all your stylesheets in the head so when you append this will add it to the bottom meaning as its cascading the bottom styles overrules everything therefore this will be the overrider for any other styles. You would not expect style elements in the body and if they are then they have been put there to override anything in its path. do you agree @Roberto

Comment: I am pretty sure inline styles would still override what OP has done. I don't know why one would use JavaScript to write CSS with normal CSS syntax. Why not just use CSS in that case? JavaScript would be used to change/set individual elements for specific purposes as far as I can imagine.

Comment: inline styles are MEANT to overrule everything and are not best practice to use so i wouldnt worry about that, as if they have been put in then they have been put in for a reason.. stylesheet would be the best to go with this i agree but what happens if he wants dynamic data being pushed in to the style so the user can change colors himself and pick them on the website.. you would then need to use something like this to make it work. @Gendarme

Comment: Yes, but then you would use something like `document.getElementById("title").style.color = "red";` Not creating `<style>` elements and *actually writing CSS* with JavaScript.

Comment: but why would you do that.. how much code you would write to change every element when you can do a solution like above in 8 lines? what dont you like with what i have done? @Gendarme

Comment: Also SEO rank you down for inline styles so doing it your way it would be a nightmare for any SEO to try to get high in google @Gendarme its not all about the code you have to think of the other factors as well

Comment: If you look at OP's post, you see that he writes `document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "width: 50px";` instead of `document.getElementByClassName("myAnimation")[0].style.width = "50px";`. It just looks incredibly weird to create a `<style>` element with JavaScript to change the style, when you can change the styles directly.

Comment: i dont understand why it would be classed as strange.. you want to have all your styles in the head and you dont want inline styles all over the place. Doing this will make it neat and easier for people to see where the styles are coming from + less code and dynamic + fast.

Comment: They are not inline styles, though. If you look at page source you won't see any inline styling. It is all in the external JS-script.

Comment: Yeah i know but in my eyes you should have everything in the head.. this allows you to do this. we will agree to disagree! ha

Comment: Fair enough. This discussion has gone way too far.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use [aphrodite](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite). It's an inline stylesheet library created for React but doesn't require React.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are doing it incorrectly. What you are doing now is to use JavaScript to create a `<style>` element in your HTML and then append text to it to change the style of your HTML-elements, instead of styling them directly with JavaScript.

The elements have an attribute called `style` which you can fetch with JavaScript.

**Style an element with regard to id:**

If you have an element with an `id` of `home`, and you want to set its background-color to red, you would do it like this:

`document.getElementById("home").style.backgroundColor = "red";`

**Style elements with regard to tag:**

Instead of using `getElementById` you will use `getElementsByTagName` which returns an array of elements.

If you want the fifth `<p>` to have the color blue, you would do it like this:

`document.getElementsByTagName("p")[4].style.color = "blue";`

If you want to do that to every `<p>` you can simply put it in a loop:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].style.color = "blue";
}
```

**Style elements with regard to class:**

Exactly the same as above, but instead of `getElementsByTagName` you use `getElementsByClassName`.

Example: `document.getElementsByClassName("slogan")[0].innerHTML = "hello";`

**Side notes:**

Writing `document.getElementById` and the others over and over again gets very repetitive. You can create method aliases for them - something like this:

```
function tag(string) {
    return document.getElementsByTagName(string);
}

function c(string) { 
    return document.getElementsByClassName(string);
}

function id(string) {
    return document.getElementById(string);
}
```

and write like this instead:

```
id("home").style.backgroundColor = "red";

tag("p")[4].style.color = "blue";

c("slogan")[0].innerHTML = "hello";
```